# RoboSpice and TCP Connection

Tags: android, robospice

I'm not sure if I should post this here or on github, but I got a weird ticket raised by a client saying :

> One of the problem we see, that might be the root cause of the API
>   dying is that the API replies to the App with the data and HTTP 200 OK
>   and closes the TCP session.
>
> However the app does not acknowledge the closing of the session and
>   continues trying to use the same old TCP session that is in close wait
>   state on the server.

Now I'm not an HTTP stack expert nor have time to dig in the Robospice code, so my question is : Is it a client side or a server side issue ? If it's client side, is it a Robospice issue, or a "code12, dumb programmer at work" issue.

The API is written in Python (Flask) and runs along an OpenStack infrastructure.

My project currently use :

```
Android 4.+
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14'
```

Thanks for any suggestions !

Comment: Is it possible that you use OkHttp as well? It is possible that OkHttp is reusing the TCP connection.
(As a side note, there is no need to have both the `robospice` and `robospice-retrofit` dependencies included. Only `robospice-retrofit` is enough to do the trick.)

Comment: Complementary link: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Connections#addresses

Comment: Thanks for pointing that I only need 1 of the 2 compile statement, I think in earlier version you needed both.

Comment: Looked at my libs, and I dont see OkHttp